# Decorators problem: experimental syntax 'decorators-legacy' isn't currently enabled

Tags: reactjs, sass, gatsby

i'm a very gatsbyjs beginner.
I've a very simple site generated from "hello word" starter.
I added gatsby-plugin-sass and bootstrap.
In my index.js when I wrote
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";

I obtain
/src/pages/index.js: Support for the experimental syntax 'decorators-legacy' isn't currently enabled (4:1)

what's the matter?

Comment: Are you using a TypeScript starter?

Comment: no, the simplest gatsby-starter-hello-world

Answer (score 0):

You should enable `proposal-decorators`. To achieve this in Gatsby, first, you have to install the Babel plugin:

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-proposal-decorators
```

*Note: change to `yarn add @babel/plugin-proposal-decorators` if using Yarn.*

Then, add a `.babelrc` in the root of your project and add the following lines:

```
{
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"],
    "plugins": [
        ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "legacy": true }],
    ]
}
```

If you are already using a custom Babel configuration you just need to add `["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "legacy": true }]` in the plugins section.

Comment: thanks, but... now the command "gatsby develop" fails in this way:

pages/index.js: import can only be used in import() or import.meta (4:1)

Comment: the 4th line is:   
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";

Comment: Imports in JavaScript doesn't allow `@`. If you are importing a simple `.scss` file, your import should look like `import 'boostrap/scss/boostrap.scss'`